# Error in atom package ternjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, atom-editor, ternjs

For web development (and more), my favorite editor is the great atom editor, the open source project by github.

Like many code editors, we can extend it by installing a lot of plugins. Among others, I use [atom-ternjs](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ternjs):

> Javascript code intelligence for atom with tern.js. Uses suggestion provider by autocomplete-plus.

Today I get this error into a 'alert styled' flash message box in the editor window's top right corner:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'CallExpression' of undefined at findTypeFromContext.NewExpression (/home/poremil/.atom/packages/atom-ternjs/node_modules/tern/lib/infer.js:1588:18) at Object.exports.typeFromContext (/home/poremil/.atom/packages/atom-ternjs/node_modules/tern/lib/infer.js:1623:24) at Object.findCompletions [as run] (/home/poremil/.atom/packages/atom-ternjs/node_modules/tern/lib/tern.js:684:23) at run (/home/poremil/.atom/packages/atom-ternjs/node_modules/tern/lib/tern.js:218:30) at Object.exports.withContext (/home/poremil/.atom/packages/atom-ternjs/node_modules/tern/lib/infer.js:774:18) at /home/poremil/.atom/packages/atom-ternjs/node_modules/tern/lib/tern.js:225:13 at analyzeAll (/home/poremil/.atom/packages/atom-ternjs/node_modules/tern/lib/tern.js:339:15) at doRequest (/home/poremil/.atom/packages/atom-ternjs/node_modules/tern/lib/tern.js:209:5) at Object.signal.mixin.request (/home/poremil/.atom/packages/atom-ternjs/node_modules/tern/lib/tern.js:149:7) at respond (/home/poremil/.atom/packages/atom-ternjs/node_modules/tern/bin/tern:224:10)

However, a didn't notice any specific bug in my workflow. That said, I would want to understand what happend.

I also opened [an issue](https://github.com/tststs/atom-ternjs/issues/115) on the github project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this does look like a bug.
Here is a simplified extract from the breaking code:

```
var findTypeFromContext = {
  NewExpression: function() { return this.CallExpression() }
  ,CallExpression: function() { console.log('calling expression'); }
}
var finder = findTypeFromContext['NewExpression'];
finder();
```

This breaks because of the *this* keyword.

1. The `var finder = findTypeFromContext['NewExpression'];` assignment takes NewExpression method "out" (detaching from the parent object).
2. By this assignment the *this* keyword now points to the current parent object - where CallExpression does not exists.

My quick-fix would be to immediately call the function on the object so *this* is still pointing at the right place:

```
var findTypeFromContext = {
  NewExpression: function() { this.CallExpression() }
  ,CallExpression: function() { console.log('calling expression'); }
}
findTypeFromContext['NewExpression']();
```